# Is it true that $|∇u(x)|^2\chi_\Omega=|\nabla (u \chi_\Omega)|^2$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, distribution-theory

Let $u\in L^\infty(\Omega)\cap H^1(\Omega)$ with $\Omega$ open, bounded and regular (as you wish) domain of $\mathbb{R}^N$. Is it true that

$$
\int_\Omega |\nabla u(x)|^2 \mathrm{d} x= \int_{\mathbb{R}^N}| \nabla (u(x) \chi_\Omega(x))|^2 \mathrm{d} x
$$

where $u \chi_\Omega$ is the extension of $u$ by zero outside $\Omega$?

Comment: I'd say this is the case only if $u \in H^1_0(\Omega)$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_space#Functions_vanishing_at_the_boundary

Comment: What is the meaning of $\nabla$ on the right? In general, $u\chi_\Omega$ is not in any Sobolev space. (For example, take $u\equiv 1$)